# Align Gridview Columns value in left side

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

Align Column values in left Side I'm using this code

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object o, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   //Assumes the Price column is at index 4
   if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        e.Row.Cells[2].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
}
```

but im not getting, because I'm controlling grid like this

```
 protected void GridView1_DataBound1(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    for (int rowIndex = grdtcwisetarget.Rows.Count - 2; rowIndex >= 0; rowIndex--)
    {
       GridViewRow gvRow = grdtcwisetarget.Rows[rowIndex];
       GridViewRow gvPreviousRow = grdtcwisetarget.Rows[rowIndex + 1];
       for (int cellCount = 0; cellCount < 2;cellCount++)
       {
           if (gvRow.Cells[cellCount].Text == gvPreviousRow.Cells[cellCount].Text)
           {
               if (gvPreviousRow.Cells[cellCount].RowSpan < 2)
               {
                  gvRow.Cells[cellCount].RowSpan = 2;
               }
               else
               {
                  gvRow.Cells[cellCount].RowSpan =
                  gvPreviousRow.Cells[cellCount].RowSpan + 1;
               }
             gvPreviousRow.Cells[cellCount].Visible = false;
           }
         }
       }
    }
```

Comment: i'm tried this code also      protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object o, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            //Assumes the Price column is at index 4
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                e.Row.Cells[2].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
        }

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
  foreach (GridViewRow  row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                cell.Attributes.CssStyle["text-align"] = "left";
            }
        }
```

moreover check this property `ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign`

```
<Columns>
  //any type of column here 
    ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" ItemStyle-Width="80" />
</Columns>
```

for your particular columns only

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in grdTest.Rows)
        {
            row.Cells["cell index here"].Attributes.CssStyle["text-align"] = "left";
        }
```

Comment: ,,thanks for ur response,,,,rex i got it,,,,but all columns aligned left ,,,,but i need only one column left side,,,others columns right values are numeric ,,,thats y

Comment: for only one column ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" for that column only

Comment: i am binding data dynamically Rex

Comment: but the column definition is given where you define the grid, in the aspx page

Comment: i am binding dynamically,,,so i dont have boundfield here,,,then how can i use <column>tags???

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
e.Row.Cells[2].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;// Not Right
```

And must use *RowDataBound* event .

Comment: @REx and Ramesh,,,thanks for u r response,,,,rex i got it,,,,but all columns align left ,,,,but i need only one column left side,,,others columns values are numeric ,,,thats y